# How to add comparator to inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, comparator

```
    public class Prerequisites {

        private class Course implements Comparator<Course> {
            public String name;
            public LinkedList<Course> requiredFor;
            public LinkedList<Course> prerequisites;

            Course(String name) {
                requiredFor = new LinkedList<Course>();
                prerequisites = new LinkedList<Course>();
                this.name = name;
            }

            @Override
            public int compare(Course c0, Course c1) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]*");
                Matcher matcher0 = p.matcher(c0.name);
                Matcher matcher1 = p.matcher(c1.name);
                matcher0.find();
                matcher1.find();
                int courseNumber0 = Integer.parseInt(c0.name.substring(matcher0.end(),c0.name.length()));
                int courseNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(c1.name.substring(matcher1.end(),c1.name.length()));
                if(courseNumber0 > courseNumber1) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if(courseNumber0 < courseNumber1) {
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    return matcher0.group().compareTo(matcher1.group());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(){
                return this.name;
            }
        }
    public void compare(String args[]) {
        Course c0 = new Course("CSE110");
        Course c1 = new Course("DSE110");
        LinkedList<Course> courses = new LinkedList<Course>();
        courses.add(c0);
        courses.add(c1);
        **Collections.sort(courses);** //gives compiler error

    }
 }
```

Why adding Collections.sort() for this inner class is not working ? I am not able to figure that out from the compiler error.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to include the compile error you're getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably meant [to implement `Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), not `Comparator`.

That's what [the `Collections#sort` method expects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be implementing [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), not [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort(courses);`

**-** If its the above, what you want to implement then its `java.lang.Comparable` Interface that you want to implement, and not java.util.Comparator Interface.

**-** Moreover `Comparable Interface` is used when you need to Sort the item on the basis of only one attribute.

But if you want to **sort the items on the basis of more than one Attribute**, then please implement `java.util.Comparator Interface`.

`Collections.sort(List l, Comparator<T> t);`